# Parsing of JSON array returning blank array

Tags: ios, iphone, json

I have an array which is of below kind.

```
    {"Hotweeks":[{"Image":"http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/0970E01L.jpg","Description":"Ocean Shores, WA","PostTitle":"Windjammer Condominiums"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970O01L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970I08L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970I06L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970I04L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970i03L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970I02L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970I01L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970E02L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0970E01L"},
    {"Image":"http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/0936E01L.jpg","Description":"Manson, WA","PostTitle":"Wapato Point"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936O05L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936O04L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936O03L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936O02L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936O01L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936I01L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936E03L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936E02L"},
    {"Image":"","Description":"","PostTitle":"0936E01L"}]}
```

Which I am trying to parse using the below code.

```
NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
        NSLog(@"Size of array is %ld",[array count]);


        NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *test = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Image"];
        NSLog(@"Value for image is %@",test);
```

This is returning null in Nslog.

Comment: what's the output for this? `NSLog(@"Size of array is %ld",[array count]);`

Comment: 0 it is means its not making array

Comment: Your json is incorrect . Description is not string as ending  " is missing

Comment: It was just a type error. Its there

Comment: @Saty did you get any thing in error ?

Comment: And what is the value of `error`???

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. -- You didn't include the value of `error`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 …"Description":"Ocean Shores, WA,"PostTitle":…
```

is missing a `"` after `Ocean Shores, WA`. It should be

```
 …"Description":"Ocean Shores, WA","PostTitle":…
```

Use a JSON validator to check for this type of thing. There are many to pick from. I use the Chrome apps JSON Lint and JSON Editor.

Comment: As marosoaie points out, it's also an object (dictionary) not an array at the top level.

Answer (score 0):

The top level of your Json file is an object, not an array (it doesn't start with '['). That being said, if you check `array`'s type like this: `NSLog("%@", [array class]` you'll probably see it's a NSDictionary.
To get the array you can do this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[returnString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
NSArray *array = jsonDict[@"Hotweeks"];

NSLog(@"Size of array is %ld",[array count]);

NSDictionary *dictionary = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *test = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Image"];
NSLog(@"Value for image is %@",test);
```